# Call to Bean from xhtml not work

Tags: java, html, jsf, xhtml

I must create new features in a framework that I do not know but it works on jsf that I know, I generate the xhtml but when calling the Bean # {mangeBean.data}, it does not work.

this is what I have in the XML declarations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
```

What should I consider to call the Bean?

Answer (score 0):

You must annotate this bean with the ManagedBean annotation. For example:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class MyBean implements Serializable {

        //Your presentation logic    
    }
```